# Date picker bootstrap doesn't work on sidebar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, sidebar

I have one date-picker bootstrap on sidebar and when I open my page it appears strangely, I don't know why.

My sidebar date filter :

```
<li class="sidebar-filter">
<div id="%filter_id%" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" class="input-group date-picker input-daterange input-icon right sidebar-select2" >
    <input id="%filter_id%_from" name="%filter_name%_from" type="text" class="form-control sidebar-input" value="%value_from%" placeholder="%placeholder_from%" style="padding-left:2px!important;padding-right:0px!important;" />
    <span class="input-group-addon" data-content="%data-content%" data-placement="top" data-popover="popover">To</span>
    <input id="%filter_id%_to" name="%filter_name%_to" type="text" class="form-control sidebar-input" value="%value_to%" placeholder="%placeholder_to%" style="padding-left:2px!important;padding-right:0px!important;"/> 
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="%filter_id%_value" name="%filter_name%_value" value="" />
```

And on js when my page is ready, I do this :

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({ autoclose: true });
```

And final result :

[image]

Someone have an idea plz?

Comment: Can you shows us your console log.

Comment: I can, but I have no errors on my console..

Comment: Is it working inside the page and just giving error on sidebar only.

Comment: Yes it work in the page but not in sidebar